# Weird Result Incrementing a Short Beyond its Maximum Value

Tags: java, types, range, short

When i execute this code it gives value of s as -7616.
Why so? Is this because loss of data while converting it to short from int or something else?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
       short s=0;
       int x=123456;
       int i=8;
       s +=x;
       System.out.println(s);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! It made me think about things I haven't thought about in a long while and I had to brush up on a couple of concepts.  Thanks for helping me knock the rust off my brain.

For me this type of question is best visualized in binary (for reasons that will quickly become apparent):

Your original number (forgive the leading zeroes; I like groups of 4):

**`0001 1110 0010 0100 0000`**

A short, however, is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer according to the Java Language Specification (JLS) [section 4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2). Assigning the integer value 123456 to a short is known as a "narrowing primitive conversion" which is covered in [JLS 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).  Specifically, a "narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T."

Discarding all but the lowest 16 bits leaves us with:

**`1110 0010 0100 0000`**

In an unsigned integer this value is 57,290, however the short integer is a signed two's complement integer.  The 1 in the leftmost digit indicates a negative number; to get the value of the number you must [invert the bits and add 1](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html):

Original:

**`1110 0010 0100 0000`**

Invert the bits:

**`0001 1101 1011 1111`**

Add 1:

**`0001 1101 1100 0000`**

Convert that to decimal and add the negative sign to get **-7,616**.

Thanks again for asking the question.  It's okay to not know something so keep asking and learning.  I had fun answering...I like diving into the JLS, crazy, I know!

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail. I am expecting such a answer because in different value of integer short gives different value and that make me confused! Once again thanks!!

Comment: @Dici, because that's how it's done. If you'd like more detail than would fit in a comment, the last link in my post explains why inverting the number and adding one works to get the two's complement negative value. The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) on two's complement has a more rigorous treatment of the topic.

Answer (score 4):

You are simply overflowing the maximum value of a short :

> short: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement
>   integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of
>   32,767 (inclusive). As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can
>   use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the
>   memory savings actually matters.

What happens when there is such overflow is equivalent to this algorithm :

```
/** Returns an integer which is equal to the short obtained by the ((short) n) conversion */
public static int int2short(int n) {
    int sign      = n > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    int increment = sign * (Short.MAX_VALUE - Short.MIN_VALUE + 1);
    for ( ; n > Short.MAX_VALUE || n < Short.MIN_VALUE ; n -= increment);
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing a `short` beyond its maximum value is called overflow. When overflow occurs, the value becomes the **minimum value** of the type, and start counting up again.

So here's how you got -7616 from trying to store 0+123456 in a `short`:

```
0 --> 32767

-32768 --> 32767

-32768 --> -7616
```

In other words,

```
32768+ 32768+ 32768+ (32768 -7616) = 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

The compound assignment operator `+=` (all of them really) [cast their result](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent
>   to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1`
>   is evaluated only once.

So

```
s += x;
```

becomes

```
s = (short) (s + x);
```

Now, because `s` is a `short` and `x` is an `int`, [binary numeric promotion is performed on the `short` value before the addition is applied.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) The `short` value is converted to an `int` (which is not a problem).

```
s = (short) (8 + 123456)
s = (short) (123464)
```

The [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) applies a [narrowing primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) which

> [...] may lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and
>   range.

That's what happens

```
s = -7608
```